# How to get the first 3 words out of each cell of a range previously selected?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

What I exactly need is to get the first 3 words out of each cell of the range selected, and then set it in the same place (each cell), so that I end up with the first 3 words in each cell. It doesn´t matter the number of words there were before. Basically, I need a code with a bucle to do that with each cell in the selection.

I´ve tried to use formula local, but it doesn´t work.

```
Sub EXTRAER_NOMBRES_Y_APELLIDO()
'Convierte los textos seleccionados a formato de nombre propio
'La primera letra en mayúscula y el resto en minúsculas
'Dim CELDA As String
'Dim B As Integer
For Each CELDA In Selection
    'CELDA.Value = Left(Range("Y3"), 5)
    'Range("Y3") = Left(Range("Y3"), 5)
    'CELDA.Value = Left(CELDA, 3)
    ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=LEFT(Planilla[@Estudiante];FIND(" ";Planilla[@Estudiante])-1)"
Next CELDA
End Sub
```

What I expect is to get the first 3 words in each cell of the column (range previously selected).

Comment: Please give an example of the input data and of the desired result. Since the input data is unlikely to be uniform (like, some people don't have middle names, for example) it would be better if you could post a picture of 10 or 15 different names and the desired outcome for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a proposal, using basic Excel formulas:

- Replace the first space with an underscore
- Replace the first space with an underscore (as a result, both first spaces are replaced by underscore)
- Determine the location of the first space (which gives the location of the third space in the original text)
- Take the text, at the left of the `n`th character.

Hereby the formulas (the original text is in cell `B2`):

```
B3 : =SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"_";1)
B4 : =SUBSTITUTE(B3;" ";"_";1)
B5 : =FIND(" ";B4)
B6 : =LEFT(B2;B5-1)
```

Comment: Please, explain me well, what each of those formulas do, and how the code for that should be.

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE` is about replacing a character (a space in this case) by another one (an underscore in this case). I do this two times and as a result, the first two spaces are replaced by underscores. So, now the first space is in fact the third one. Using the `FIND` worksheet function, I find its location, and finally i take all the characters left of that space's location, which allows me to find the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

## Split Names

### Assumptions

There are two or three names per cell range (person):

- **First Name** and **Last Name** or
- **First Name**, **Middle Name** and **Last Name**.

You wanted the names from one column split into three columns.

### The Code

- Adjust the values in the constants section to fit your needs.
- You can choose the same column letter or number if you want to
  overwrite the initial data, but do this after testing the code.

---

```
Sub SplitNames()

    Const cSource As Variant = "A"  ' Source Column Letter/Number
    Const cTarget As Variant = "B"  ' Target Column Letter/Number
    Const cFirstR As Long = 2       ' Source/Target First Row Number

    Dim vntS As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntD As Variant   ' Delimited Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim LastR As Long     ' Source/Target Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long         ' Source/Target Array Row Counter

    ' Calculate Source/Target Last Row Number.
    LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, cSource).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Copy Source Range into Source Array.
    vntS = Range(Cells(cFirstR, cSource), Cells(LastR, cSource))

    ' Resize Target Array's rows to the number of rows in Source Array,
    ' but to three columns: First, Middle, Last.
    ReDim vntT(1 To UBound(vntS), 1 To 3)

    ' Copy from Source Array to Target Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)     ' Rows of Source/Target Array
        vntD = Split(vntS(i, 1))  ' Split each row of Source Array.
        vntT(i, 1) = vntD(0)      ' First Name
        If UBound(vntD) = 2 Then  ' Does have middle name.
            vntT(i, 2) = vntD(1)  ' Middle Name
            vntT(i, 3) = vntD(2)  ' Last Name
          Else                    ' Does not have middle name.
            vntT(i, 3) = vntD(1)  ' Last Name
        End If
    Next

    ' Copy Target Array into Target Range.
    Range(Cells(cFirstR, cTarget), Cells(LastR, cTarget)) _
            .Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT

End Sub
```

### Second Version

- Adjust the values in the constants section to fit your needs.
- You can choose the same column letter or number if you want to
  overwrite the initial data, but do this after testing the code.

---

```
Sub SplitNames2()

    Const cSource As Variant = "A"  ' Source Column Letter/Number
    Const cTarget As Variant = "B"  ' Target Column Letter/Number
    Const cFirstR As Long = 7       ' Source/Target First Row Number
    Const cNum As Long = 3          ' Number of Words

    Dim vntS As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntD As Variant   ' Delimited Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim LastR As Long     ' Source/Target Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long         ' Source/Target Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Long         ' Delimited Array Rows Counter

    ' Calculate Source/Target Last Row Number.
    LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, cSource).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Copy Source Range into Source Array.
    vntS = Range(Cells(cFirstR, cSource), Cells(LastR, cSource))

    ' Resize Target Array's rows to Source Array,
    ReDim vntT(1 To UBound(vntS), 1 To 1)

    ' Copy from Source Array to Target Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)     ' Rows of Source/Target Array
        vntD = Split(vntS(i, 1))  ' Split each row of Source Array.
        j = UBound(vntD)
        If j > cNum - 1 Then
            j = cNum - 1
        End If
        If j <> -1 Then
            For j = 0 To j
                If j > 0 Then
                    vntT(i, 1) = vntT(i, 1) & " " & vntD(j)
                  Else
                    vntT(i, 1) = vntD(j)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    ' Copy Target Array into Target Range.
    Range(Cells(cFirstR, cTarget), Cells(LastR, cTarget)) = vntT

End Sub
```

Comment: What I exactly need is to get the first 3 words out of each cell of the range selected, and then set it in the same place (each cell), so that I end up with the first 3 words in each cell. Actually, it doesn´t matter the number of words there are before. Basically, I need a code with a bucle to do that with each cell in the selection.

Comment: @JUAN MORENO: You can edit your question. There is an EDIT button below your post. You should put all this information in there and provide a visual sample. You could have gotten 3-5 answers by now. I'll have mine ready in about 20 min.

Comment: @JUAN MORENO: I've added a second version below the first.

Comment: @JUAN MORENO: Have you changed the cSource and cTarget. They should be equal for the final version.